# How deep is the Survival Dungeon and what are the rewards?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

So I'm currently trying to muster up the stamina and courage required to venture into the depths of the Survival Dungeon. However, before I begin, I need to know just what I'm getting into and confirm that it's actually worth the effort. How many floors are in the Survival Dungeon, and what am I rewarded with if I successfully complete all of them?

Comment: dungeons is a game itself, so untagging.

Comment: @antony.trupe Whoops! Danke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Survival Dungeon is a 60 floor dungeon that randomly selects levels from the Terran Ruins, the Ignan Ruins, the Aquan Ruins, and the Zephyran Ruins. You will encounter a boss at every 10 levels. On the 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th, and 50th floors, defeating the boss will yield *a shop and a treasure chest*. The shop sells food items to heal (subject to the same price hikes as normal shop items, so keep that in mind). The treasure chest will contain a unique item (or a Thankful Statue if you've already gotten that item). Progressing to the next level is done by opening the chest, so *shop first if you're going to buy anything*.

Below are what you'll get on each floor.

- 10th Floor: **Air Emblem** - This Emblem increases the drop rate of Green Gems. Probably one of the most useful Emblem.
- 20th Floor: **Omega Ferromin** - Increases your maximum HP by 25.
- 30th Floor: **Food Emblem** - This Emblem is a very useful utility for survivability - it increases the rate at which enemies drop food for healing.
- 40th Floor: **TH Shield**: The most powerful Shield, it gives +65 Defense.
- 50th Floor: **Star Glove**: A powerful Glove, it gives +70 Attack.

Additionally, **in the shops on the 40th and 50th floors**, you can purchase the **Divine Staff**, a Staff that gives +70 Magic Attack. It's the most powerful staff in the game, so don't forget to visit the shop on those levels!

The 60th floor is a unique boss fight that is only available in the Survival Dungeon. You do not get a treasure chest or shop after defeating it, clearing it merely gives you completion of the dungeon. However, there is a special item only gotten on the 60th floor, as follows.

> The boss of the 60th floor is the **Golden Wyvern**. It's essentially an immensely powerful version of the Aeolian Wyvern (we're talking more powerful than the last boss here) that is **also non-elemental and so has no elemental weaknesses**. You can break its horns just like the Aeolian Wyvern, and this guarantees a drop of a **Gold Horn**, a Treasure that sells for 100,000 pix. Additionally, [selling the **Gold Horn** unlocks the **Ancient Gramaphone** in the Familiar Forest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27187/which-treasure-items-can-i-sell-to-unlock-more-items-and-how-do-i-obtain-them), which you can buy for 100,000 pix to unlock the last section of the Jukebox.

---

One last little thing you can find in the Survival Dungeon. The bosses of the 10th and 30th floors are randomly selected from the first four bosses of the game. However, on the 30th floor, this encounter is a Shadowy version of the boss that is more powerful. This is only noteworthy for this question in that the Shadow version of the Aeolian Wyvern has a chance to drop the Treasure **Black Horn** when one of its horns is broken. Thankfully, it is not required to obtain for anything other than being a completionist.

Answer (score 4):

There are 60 floors in the Survival Dungeon, with a boss and reward every tenth floor. The rewards are as follows ([source](http://simulationstyle.bravehost.com/Chantelise/10_18.html)):

Floor 10: Wind Crest  -- Increases chances of getting wind gems
Floor 20: L O F   --  Max HP +25
Floor 30: Food Crest   -- Increases chances of getting food
Floor 40: Absolute Territory   --   65 DEF
Floor 50: Evil Spirits of Rivers and Mountains    -- 70 ATK
Floor 60: Golden Horn*   -- Gold

> You must destroy one of the Gold Wyvern's horns for the Golden Horn to drop in order to obtain it.